# Column Highchart - Lot of column

Tags: highcharts

We have column chart, but it will display very ugly when it have lot of column, we enable the scrollbar but its not working properly. Please see the below image.

Please help me on,

- How to add margin between group of column.
- Or any other way to display the column chart with huge amount of data.

jsFiddle :

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/utq6zjh5/4/`
```

[image: Please see the below image]

Comment: you can use 'pointpadding' for this, can you show us a working example of this problem?? some thing like a jsfiddle will help us

Comment: Hi strikers, Please find below jsFiddle for same. [link]http://jsfiddle.net/harshadsph/utq6zjh5/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
xAxis: {
   min: 100   
},
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/utq6zjh5/5/

Answer (score 0):

Try setting some max to xAxis that will work,
setting both min and max to the xAxis will make a pericular range of values to be hown and the chart will be scrollable now,

```
xAxis: {
    max: 3 //3 is just a smple, just check which will work in your case
}
```

updated your fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/utq6zjh5/6/)